# What's the minimium velocity for re-entry flames to start?

Tags: reentry

Considering a space shuttle re-entering Earth, what's the minimum velocity that would cause the vehicle to start burning? Is there an equation to calculate that?

I presume it varies according to the materials that compose the shuttle and of the atmosphere.

Comment: Space shuttles do not burn on re-entry.  Not, at least, by design.

Comment: Do you literally mean burning, as in "the machine oxidizes rapidly in an exothermic reaction producing a great deal of heat and light," or as in "it starts making a fiery streak across the sky?"  In the latter case, the space shuttle is not actually burning--the fiery streak is caused by by the air that the Shuttle has heated by slamming into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spacecraft usually do not burn on re-entry, in the usual sense of burning. Burning implies a combustion reaction, which does not happen on a spacecraft designed for it, and even spacecraft not designed for it usually won't burn, because they're not made of flammable materials; they just break apart under the thermal and physical stresses.

However, upon re-entry from orbit, there is a lot of re-entry heating. This is caused by [adiabatic compression](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qe1Ueifekg), a process in which air heats up as it is compressed. The air heats up a lot from this compression, which is what causes the bright glow of re-entry. This will happen in the vicinity of any object which is traveling at [hypersonic speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersonic_speed) (speeds greater than around Mach 5), as, at that speed, the air literally cannot get out of the way in time.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLHo9ZM3Bis) does a good job of explaining re-entry heating and measures used to protect spacecraft from it, if you want to learn more.